# Rails - Efficiently checking child attributes exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Probably a really basic question but I just can't seem to figure this out.. Say I have the models clothes and colours.

What's the most efficient way of checking with Active-record if a clothing has a certain colour in it or not, where a piece of clothing has multiple colours. I would like to get a boolean if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since (presumably) many clothings can have the same colour and some clothing has many colours, you'd need a join table and (simplest case) you are using a HABTM relationship.

As you're checking a particular piece of clothing (i.e. you already have the clothing model loaded), you can do this efficiently with a model method.

You could create a method `has_colour?`

```
class Clothing < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :colours

  def has_colour?(colour)
    colours.include?(colour)
  end

end
```